# INSERT INTO TABLE .. php - variable in sql query

Tags: php, mariadb

I have php script containing following SQL query (working oK):

```
$query = 'INSERT INTO persons'.
   '(name,
     surname
     )'.'VALUES
     ( "'.$_REQUEST["name"].'",
       "'.$_REQUEST["surname"].'"
     )';
```

Where $_REQUEST["name"] and $_REQUEST["name"] are variables passed from html form.
   usin php 4.5 and MariaDB 5.5

Problem rises when i try to substitute persons by variable - eg. $table:

```
$table = "persons";

$query = 'INSERT INTO '.$table.''.
   '(name,
     surname
     )'.'VALUES
     ( "'.$_REQUEST["name"].'",
       "'.$_REQUEST["surname"].'"
     )';
```

I have been trying different variations with double qutes/single qutes/dots :). But still struggling with this.. 
Thx for possible answer.

Comment: Remove the quotes and dots for `'.$table.'` you don't need them. Also `'.'` before VALUES.

Comment: Or you know, use a more convenient/newer database API with parameter binding.

Comment: `$query = 'INSERT INTO $table (name,
     surname) VALUES
     ( "'.$_REQUEST["name"].'",
       "'.$_REQUEST["surname"].'" )';` <= give that a go, but as Mario said, parameter binding is much better and safer. vvvvvvvv

Comment: Read up on [**`mysqli` with prepared statements**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), or [**PDO with prepared statements**](http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements).

Comment: What kind of errors did you get from running the variable version of the query?

Answer (score 2):

Its a simply case of knowing how the single and double quote works in PHP

Try this

```
$table = 'persons';

$query = "INSERT INTO $table (name,surname)
             VALUES ( '{$_REQUEST['name']}', 
                      '{$_REQUEST['surname']}' )";
```

Now of course you should not be using the mysql_* extension anymore but if you have to you should at least try and sanitize the input values before you use them

So the code becomes

```
// do at least this to sanitize the inputs
$_REQUEST['name'] = mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['name']);
$_REQUEST['surname'] = mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['surname']);

$query = "INSERT INTO $table (name,surname)
             VALUES ( '{$_REQUEST['name']}', 
                      '{$_REQUEST['surname']}' )";
```

Comment: So what happens if `$_REQUEST['name']` contains a single quote?

Comment: I added some basic sanitization to the answer

Comment: Add `stripslashes()` too. ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
$table_name = 'persons';

$query = "insert into ".$table_name." (name,surname) values ('".$_REQUEST['name']."','".$_REQUEST['surname']."') ";
```